# Librería "gdal_priv.h" en C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, librería

Tengo problemas para compilar un programa de C++ en Ubuntu.
El programa se compone de una librería propia `contours.h` dentro de está librería se manda a llamar o se agrega `gdal_priv.h`.

Ya instale gdal en linux (es una maquina virtual) mediante los siguientes comandos:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable  
$ sudo apt-get update  
$ sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

También está instalado python.

El problema que me aparece al compilar el programa principal (de la siguiente forma):

```
g++ -o ejecutable programa.cpp
```

Es que el directorio o archivo `#include "gdal_priv.h"` no existe o no se encuentra. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Estuve investigando un poco y no se si las especificaciones de mi laptop afecten o impidan el funcionamiento de la parte de `gdal`: AMD 9, 8 RAM, 1 TB ROM, sin tarjeta gráfica.

Si sirve de algo, el programa es para marching squares y esta de forma paralela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder utilizar librerías para compilar normalmente se instalan los paquetes `x-dev`. Déjame mirar:

```
$ apt-file search gdal_priv.h
libgdal-dev: /usr/include/gdal/gdal_priv.h
```

Efectivamente. Así que debes hacer `sudo apt install libgdal-dev`. Una vez instalado el paquete, deberias poder compilar.

Comment: Me funcionó, aunque a la librería la tuve que poner como ´´#include "gdal/gdal_priv.h"´´

Comment: O que le indiques al compilador que también use el directorio /usr/include/gdal para buscar headers.